# ¿Cómo hacer para aceptar un error de conexión a la base de datos como un valor correcto?

Tags: php, mysqli

Ahora mismo estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación y estoy en un punto donde necesito hacer un comprobador de conexión. En base a unos inputs anteriores con los datos de conexión, tengo un JS que mediante AJAX hace la petición al servidor para ver si la conexión existe y es correcta. Hasta aquí, todo bien, el problema es el siguiente:

Si la conexión es satisfactoria (entendemos por conexión, la conexión al servidor y a la base de datos, es decir, los inputs son dirección del servidor, usuario de la base de datos, contraseña de la base de datos y nombre de la tabla), pues muestra un mensaje satisfactorio, pero si la conexión no es satisfactoria, muestra un mensaje de que la conexión no es satisfactoria, pero además, al tener los errores activados, muestra el log de error en el cliente.

Lo que necesito conseguir es que si la conexión no es satisfactoria, no se muestre este cuadro de error, sólo el mensaje, aunque los errores estén activados (que en un futuro no lo estarán, y por lo tanto este error, solucionado o no, no aparecerá, pero me gustaría que no estuviera el error).

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect($_GET['servidor'], $_GET['usuario'], $_GET['contrasenya'], $_GET['nombre']) or die ("No se ha podido establecer la conexión.");
    if ( $conn ) {
        echo "La conexión ha sido establecida satisfactoriamente.";
    } else {
        echo "La conexión no ha sido establecida satisfactoriamente.";
    }

?>
```

Como veis, el código es excesivamente sencillo, pero no necesito nada más para verificar la conexión. Y aquí el error del que os hablo por si no quedó claro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, mi objetivo es que aparezca el mensaje del echo (o a través de un die, esto es indiferente), sin el cuadro naranja **incluso con los errores activados**.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Coloca `error_reporting(0);` encima de la conexión:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
        $conn = mysqli_connect($_GET['servidor'], $_GET['usuario'], $_GET['contrasenya'], $_GET['nombre']) or false;
        if ( $conn ) {
            echo "La conexión ha sido establecida satisfactoriamente.";
        } else {
            echo "La conexión no ha sido establecida satisfactoriamente.";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Es una solución, pero no precisamente la que busco. Lo que necesito es que un error de conexión pueda ser una opción correcta. Es decir, que el error no aparezca, porque que la conexión falle también es un resultado correcto. No sé si me explico. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: ¿Dices para que entre al if?

Comment: No. En PHP que la conexión a la base de datos falle, tira un warning porque espera que la conexión sea correcta, yo lo que necesito es que espere que la conexión pueda ser correcta o incorrecta y que no muestre ese error de manera natural, sin tener que hacer que "desaparezca" (aún estando ahí). Una especie de try-catch que coja la query en el try y si da el error esperado, muestre el mensaje de error sin el cuadro naranja (no porque se haya ocultado con el error_reporting), sino porque un error de conexión esté permitido y no tire un warning.

Comment: Creo que ya entendí, ¿quieres capturar el mensaje solamente? En tu caso: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Lo que quiero lograr es que PHP me permita introducir una conexión incorrecta y no me muestre ese cuadro naranja sin deshabilitr los errores. Lo que necesito es una forma de intentar hacer una conexión (simplemente para comprobar que existe, o no) y que tanto "true" como "false" sean opciones para PHP correctas, es decir, que que tire false, no tire un warning. No sé si me estoy explicando con claridad, al final, lo que quiero es conseguir corregir ese warning sin hacerlo desaparecer con un error_reporting(0);

Comment: Perdona que no pueda ayudarte, modifiqué el código para que $conn en caso de que la conexión sea correcta la guarde, y si no es correcta, guarda false. No sé como ocultar el mensaje de warning de otra manera, espero alguien pueda ayudarte en eso

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que las variables $_GET estén iniciadas y no estén vacías. Además checkeá que la base y el archivo compartan el número de IP, para que localhost sea correcto.
Luego podés verificar los errores con mysqli_connect_error().

Answer (score 0):

Hay un ejemplo en el manual de php: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php#110971

Aquí adaptado a tus `$_GET[]`

```
<?php
// activamos los errores
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


// configuramos mysqli

// Ensure reporting is setup correctly
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

// Connect function for database access
function connect($host,$usr,$pw,$db) {
  try {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$usr,$pw,$db);
    return $mysqli;
  } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    // hacer algo aquí o dejar que otro se encargue
    throw $e;
  }
}

try {
  $conn = connect(
    $_GET['servidor'],
    $_GET['usuario'],
    $_GET['contrasenya'],
    $_GET['nombre']);
  //'host','username','password','database');
  echo 'Conectado a la database';
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Hubo Un error!".PHP_EOL;
  echo "e: " . mysqli_connect_error().PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

- le decis al mysqli que reporte todo
- en una función probas conectar usando try catch
- si hay error (catch) relanzas (throw) la excepción

---

- llamas a la función con tus parametros usando try catch
- si hay error mostras el error ( o no )